# Invalid Cyrillic filename in chrome.downloads.download in Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome-extension

I get `Error: Invalid filename` when I try to download any file with Cyrillic name in my Google Chrome Extension by `chrome.downloads.download`. It works fine in Windows, but it does not work in Fedora Linux 39 Workstation. If I change my OS locale to Belarusian -- I get the same error.

Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

It is a simple code in background script:

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url : e.data.link,
    filename : name,
});
```